# How to receive OPT from server in Android App

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hey everyone i am new in android 
 and i am working on a app this app confirm the user info through Mobile Number and i am sending `OTP` using server but i want when `OTP` receive then OPT read automatically my app

this code send request to server and server send an `OTP`

**Code is**

```
  public  class AsyncTaslMobile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
   {
    final String mobile_no =mobileNumber.getText().toString();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


        String url = "http://my localhost.com/";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("form");
                            String site = jsonResponse.getString("site"),
                                    network = jsonResponse.getString("network");
                            Log.d("Response-------"+site,"------>"+network);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("Response-------","------>"+response);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        )
        {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                // the POST parameters:
                params.put("mobile", mobile_no);
                params.put("akey","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                Log.d("Value is ----------",">"+params);
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(postRequest);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() 
   {
    }
}
```

i want create a receiver code for this activity

Comment: You have to create a broadcast which should receive incoming sms coming to your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I am not wrong then you want to verify the mobile number of the user by sending the OTP to the desired mobile number and the app should read the OTP automatically and send the same OTP back to the server. 
if so, then this can be done by using Dynamic receiver.

```
    private BroadcastReceiver Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
                if (intentExtras != null) {
                    Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                        String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();//it will give the whole sms body which is sent from the server

// if smsBody contains words separated with space e.g. OTP 1234 then you can get the otp value by below code. 
                      //  String[] elements = smsBody.split(" ");
                      //  String otp=elements[1];//it will return otp value i.e. 1234
  //if smsBody contains only otp value e.g. 1234, then smsBody will become the OTP
           **use your HTTP request to send otp back to the server here**        

                    }

                }

            }};
```

Now you can send this otp back to the server by using SMS Manager(for offline) or by using  HTTP request in your case.

**Don't forget to register your receiver in doInBackground() method and unregister it in your activity onDestoy() method**

Comment: Thanks for replying i have a long msg like. Dear member your one time verification cade is WL12. please verify your mobile number then how to spilt that msg @Baqir

Comment: you can split msg by using  String[] elements = smsBody.split(" "); this will split the message by space and put each words in 'elements' array of string. then you can get your otp by using elements[position] e.g. in your case like msg is "Dear member your one time verification cade is WL12"  String otp=elements[8]; starting with index postion 0, gives WL12

Comment: thanks for replying its include commas points like"Dear member, your one time password code is. WL12" that way its same string or different

Comment: if it has fixed format then you can use string functions  or regular expression to search for particular word in the sentence or word after particular character like "." in this case . you have to provide some logic  which can easily get by searching on google

Answer (score 0):

Google has [strictly prohibited](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?visit_id=637589018394465838-3927191226&rd=1) the usage of READ_SMS permission for getting OTP from SMS.

Since we can’t use the READ_SMS permission anymore, Google has given some other choices to implement automatic SMS verification using [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever). With the SMS Retriever API, we can perform SMS-based user verification in our Android app automatically, without requiring the user to manually type verification codes, and without requiring any extra app permissions.

For more information [check out this tutorial](https://medium.com/programming-lite/automatic-sms-verification-with-sms-retriever-api-in-android-6bf6ab7ee6c0).